# Flutter build iOS error : Encountering error while build flutter app in iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to build flutter app in iOS device directly running at android studio but it prompt me this error below :

> Running Xcode build... Xcode build done.
> 12.7s Installing and launching...
>
> - thread #3, queue = 'com.apple.root.default-qos', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
>   frame #0: 0x000000019096dec4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
>
> Target 0: (Runner) stopped.

After running in Xcode, this is the error it shows up :

The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions at https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to set a valid application ID. Google Ad Manager publishers, follow instructions at [https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist."](https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist.%22)

**This is my info.plist :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-4326637290771071~7544496339</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Stopcard</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Can someone kindly help me on the issues ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please run this though xcode and it will give you better insights of the error

Comment: hi I already run through Xcode. I have update what error shows up in Xcode

Comment: Can you post your info.plist here please?

Comment: already added info.plist

Answer (score 0):

You have to add skAdNetworkKey for google like the following

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
 <array>
   <dict>
    <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
    <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
  </dict>
</array>
```